# jquery validate a comma separated list of positive integers between 1 and 100

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have a form where the user enters a comma separated list of positive numbers. How do I check their input with jquery during validation to verify that they have only entered numbers between 1 to100 and commas?

Currently iam using the below code

```
^[0-9](,[0-9])*$
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please only use the jQuery Validate tag for questions about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern:

```
^[0-9]|[0-9]{2}|100(?:,(?:[0-9]|[0-9]{2}|100))*$
```

The pattern `[0-9]|[0-9]{2}|100` matches a single number between 0 and 100.  This is then followed by an optional comma and another matching numbers, that quantity occurring zero or more times.

You may explore this pattern using the demo link below.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Your code will pass any numbers e. g. `99999,88888`

You need something more strict:

`^([1-9][0-9]?|100)(,([1-9][0-9]?|100))*$`

For 200:

`^([1-9][0-9]?|1[1-9][0-9]|200)(,([1-9][0-9]?|1[1-9][0-9]|200))*$`

for 300:

`^([1-9][0-9]?|[12][1-9][0-9]|300)(,([1-9][0-9]?|[12][1-9][0-9]|300))*$`

Comment: @Kosh Very Thanks very much. It is working. how can i modify this to include values up to 200 or 300